# Border-Bottom conflicts with my dropdown menu(?)

Tags: html, css, css-position, dropdown

This is my first project using HTML and CSS so I'm pretty much a newbie for this language. I think my dropdown menu is conflicting with the bottom-border because it won't show up. This is both my HTML and CSS code for it.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: white;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

header {
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  height: 600px;
}

.navbar {
  width: 85%;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 60px 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.logo {
  width: 160px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.navbar .dropdown {
  display: none;
}

.navbar ul li:hover .dropdown {
  display: block;
}

.navbar ul li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 20px;
  position: relative;
}

.navbar ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

.navbar ul li::after {
  content: '';
  height: 3px;
  width: 0;
  background: teal;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.navbar ul li:hover::after {
  width: 100%;
}

button {
  list-style: none;
  border: none;
  background: teal;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 15px;
  transition: 0.4s;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="banner">
    <div class="navbar">
      <img src="icon.png" class="logo">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
        <ul class="dropdown">
          <li><a href="#">Healthcare</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Cosmetic</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Misc.</a></li>
        </ul>
        <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Register</a></li>
      </ul>
      <button type="button"><a href="#"></a>Login</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

I already tried many options from various sources and It still won't work. I think the problem lays somewhere between the code for the border-bottom but I'm not sure.

Comment: The selector `.navbar ul li:hover .dropdown` is a descendant one, i.e. dropdown must be located inside `.navbar ul li` to be targeted. These elements are siblings at the moment. Check [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a lot to fix in your code. I fixed the essential things, among these:

- The dropdown `ul` should be a *parent* of its main menu `li`
- `position: absolute` and `position: relative` for the dropdown and
  its parent `li`, and according `top`and `margin` settings for the
  dropdown and its `li` children
- *No* general `overflow: hidden`, since this will hide the submenu being an absolutely positioned child of another element
- some other CSS details - see below

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: white;
}

body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

header {
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  height: 600px;
}

.navbar {
  width: 85%;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 60px 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.logo {
  width: 160px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.navbar .dropdown {
  display: none;
}

.navbar ul li:hover .dropdown {
  display: block;
}
.navbar > ul > li {
  position: relative;
}
.navbar > ul > li > .dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  top: 1.4em;
}
.navbar .dropdown li {
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
}
.navbar ul li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 20px;
  position: relative;
}

.navbar ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

.navbar ul li::after {
  content: '';
  height: 3px;
  width: 0;
  background: teal;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.navbar ul li:hover::after {
  width: 100%;
}

button {
  list-style: none;
  border: none;
  background: teal;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 15px;
  transition: 0.4s;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="banner">
    <div class="navbar">
      <img src="icon.png" class="logo">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Products</a>
          <ul class="dropdown">
            <li><a href="#">Healthcare</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Cosmetic</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Misc.</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Register</a></li>
      </ul>
      <button type="button"><a href="#"></a>Login</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a li wrapper for the dropdown menu. Otherwise, there is no element where you can hover over. Try this:

```
<li>
  dropdown
  <ul class="dropdown">
    <li><a href="#">Healthcare</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Cosmetic</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Misc.</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

From there you can carry on with the stylings.